# extract string from url

Tags: regex, preg-match

I need some help in writing a regular expression to extract few strings *(lets say 2 fields)* from URL.

I really want to say here **not extracting URL from a string.**

Lets say my URL something like this:

```
http:// example.com/conversion/?param1=dhkw121?param2=dhja143&uuid=jsbdwbjb-fwjdbw-wdvvw-wj
```

Or the URL type can be like this:

```
http:// example.com/conversion/param1=dhkw121%uuid=dbjbjbcs-fbsj-fsjbjs-fsj /param2=dhja143
```

From the above URL, I must extract `param1` and `param2` values exclusively those 2 and strings individually.

I tried to read some stuff using regular expression in PHP , but seems its not just regular regular expression , its more included with back references and stuff.

This is what I tried, something like this:

```
.*(param1\=.*param2\=.*)\&?.*
```

I am completely  new with this kind of complex extractions, can any one help me please ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo He is using PHP and he tagged the question with [tag:preg-match].

Comment: Why use regex for that at all? There are `parse_url()` & `parse_str()`

Comment: for some strict reason  i am limited to use regex , btw i tried with parsing. Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the params are alphanumeric only. If so, I would suggest using `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all("/param[12]=(\w+)/", $url, $results);
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/dG8yD4).

Or if you want to get them as element 1 and 2 from an array:

```
preg_match_all("/param1=(\w+).*?param2=(\w+)/", $url, $results);
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/aZ4aC4).

[ideone demo to show array results structure](http://ideone.com/D7Ni1O).

Comment: A parameter's value can contains other chars than `\w`

Comment: hej, Thank you so much, this cleared my question. adding to that , what if my param1 is something like this 

param1= fgs-132-242 ,sorry for not making my ques more clearly

Comment: @MahiAntham do you perhaps know what characters the params can have, or otherwise, characters the param cannot have? I'm not that familiar with how urls are made up, but I could enhance the regex based on that.

Comment: @MahiAntham In the meantime, you can perhaps use `/param1=([\w-]+).*?param2=([\w-]+)/` to include alphanumeric characters and dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
param1=([^&]+).*param2=([^&]+)
```

param1 value will be in group 1 and param2 value in grpup 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should suit your needs:

```
(param1|param2|anyotherparam)=([^/?&]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/S1RKfWbtGc1nh_YB)

Iterate over the matches:

- first group #1 contains the name of the param
- second group contains its value

Check by yourself: [demo](http://regexr.com?3652f).